# How do I set an element in a linked list by the index?

Tags: java

So I need to make this method to set an element a certain object by index. For example I would input index 5, and it would set whatever I chose for the object in index 5. I'm using a linked list for this. Here's the method so far..

```
public void setElement(int index, Object element) {
   ListIterator iterator = listIterator();   
}
```

I have no clue how to do this. I'm using nodes by the way. Also the ListIterator class is just the ListIterator interface. It has the methods of next, hasNext, add, remove and set. I just don't know how I would go about doing this. Could someone guide me in the right direction?

EDIT: I'm using my own implemented link list.

Here's what I just wrote which seems like I'm on the right track, but it's still not working.

```
 public void setElement(int index, Object element) {
       ListIterator iterator = listIterator();
       int count = 0;      
       while(iterator.hasNext()) {
           count++;
           if(count == index){
               iterator.set(element);
           }
       }       
   }
```

Comment: I think you can use Map for this ?

Comment: Count each node up to the required index as iterate over the list.  Insert the new node at that position and relink the links

Comment: Do you mean `java.util.LinkedList` when you say "linked list"? Surely [`list.set(5, object)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/LinkedList.html#set(int,%20E)) does this?

Comment: are you implementing your own linked list ? or just using `LinkedList<>`?

Comment: @AndyTurner the parameters are list.set(Object name)

Comment: @Suds2 Please look at the javadoc I have linked. It takes two parameters. How else would you indicate that you want to set the *5th* element to a particular value?

Answer (score 2):

> I'm using a linked list

so considering you are using [LinkedList](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/LinkedList.html)

If you want to insert new object in the specific index  and move next all elements to the right use

```
add(int index, E element)
```

[add(int index, E element)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/LinkedList.html#add%28int,%20E%29)

If you replace the existing object at the specific position

```
set(int index, E element)
```

[set(int index, E element)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/LinkedList.html#set%28int,%20E%29)